# How do I count how many span of the same id on my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html code:

```
<span id="post"></span>
<span id="post"></span>
<span id="post"></span>
<span id="post"></span>
<span id="post"></span>
<span id="post"></span>
<span id="post"></span>
<span id="post"></span>
<span id="post"></span>
<span id="post"></span>
```

I want to count how many spans are there with the `id="post"` in my page. when I tried to use `.length` and `alert` I got `1`
what is the way to do this ?

Comment: This markup is incorrect. **IDs should be unique**.

Comment: You don't. IDs are supposed to uniquely identify "things". You'll get erroneous results if you use the same ID twice or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use `class` instead of `id`.

Like:

```
<span class="post"></span>
<span class="post"></span>
<span class="post"></span>
<span class="post"></span>
<span class="post"></span>
<span class="post"></span>
<span class="post"></span>
<span class="post"></span>
<span class="post"></span>
<span class="post"></span>
```

And

```
alert($('span.post').length);
```

Comment: @ElliotB Sorry, just had to say hi. :)

Answer (score 2):

IDs must be unique. Try using classes instead. Then you could do this:

```
alert(document.getElementsByClass("post").length);

// or jQuery
alert($(".post").size());
```

That'd give you the correct amount of spans.